# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous on machine learning model for medicine

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to build a machine learning model on python with Tensorflow that predicts the probability of having a high grade brain tumor according to two given values of MRI spectroscopy (lactate and lipids). So, this is a two input model.

But, when I run it, it launches the following exception:

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 1, 1
y sizes: 23
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

The code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np

# Define the input layers for "lipidos" and "lactato"

lipidos_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(23,), name="lipidos_input")

lactato_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(23,), name="lactato_input")

# Hidden layers for the "lipidos" branch

lipidos_hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(lipidos_input)

lipidos_hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(lipidos_hidden1)

# Hidden layers for the "lactato" branch

lactato_hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(lactato_input)

lactato_hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(lactato_hidden1)

# Concatenate the output of both branches

merged = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([lipidos_hidden2, lactato_hidden2])

# Additional hidden layer

hidden_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(merged)

# Output layer with a sigmoid activation function for binary classification

output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="output")(hidden_layer)

# Create the model

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[lipidos_input, lactato_input], outputs=output_layer)

# Compile the model

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Entry data

lipidos_data = np.array([

    0.016,

    0.03,

    0.05,

    0.0008,

    0.009,

    0.01,

    0.015,

    0.15,

    0.004,

    0.016,

    0.09,

    0.003,

    0.001,

    0.003,

    0.012,

    0.01,

    0.011,

    0.01,

    0.003,

    0.02,

    0.03,

    0.001,

    0

], dtype=float)

lactato_data = np.array([

    0.015,

    0.021,

    0.043,

    0.0014,

    0.011,

    0.01,

    0.015,

    0.03,

    0.02,

    0.012,

    0.075,

    0.0025,

    0.005,

    0.01,

    0.028,

    0.011,

    0.11,

    0.032,

    0.0045,

    0.006,

    0.005,

    0,

    0.002

], dtype=float)

alto_grado_data = np.array([

    1,

    1,

    1,

    1,

    1,

    1,

    1,

    1,

    1,

    1,

    1,

    0,

    0,

    1,

    1,

    1,

    1,

    1,

    0,

    1,

    1,

    0,

    0

], dtype=int)

# Reshape the input data to 2D arrays

lipidos_data = lipidos_data.reshape(-1, 23)

lactato_data = lactato_data.reshape(-1, 23)

# Fit the model

model.fit([lipidos_data, lactato_data], alto_grado_data, epochs=100, batch_size=8)

# Predict alto_grado for a given lipidos and lactato value

lipidos_value = np.array([[0.015]], dtype=float)

lactato_value = np.array([[0.015]], dtype=float)

prediction = model.predict([lipidos_value, lactato_value])

predicted_alto_grado = round(prediction[0][0])

print("Predicted alto_grado:", predicted_alto_grado)
```

Any opinion would be a big help. Thanks in advance!

I've tried reshaping the inputs and multiplying them 23 times before the model.fit but the accuracy was terribly bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure:

```
lipidos_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(23,), name="lipidos_input")
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="output")(hidden_layer)
```

Your input layer says 23 neurons and your output dense-layer has 1 single neuron. During training you provide, e.g. `lactato_data` with shape (23,) which fits the input layer, but `alto_grado_data` has shape (1, 23) which would fit the model only if your input would have the shape (23, 23). Or in other words, all 23 elements in your input are consumed to construct a solution for the very first (and only) value in your `alto_grado_data`  And the error actually tells you that. The models assumes that it has 23 samples (to achieve the output), but is provided only with 1 (of length 23) in the input

In my opinion the correct number of neurons in the input layer would have to be 1 too. Then in your training, you have 23 examples (lipidos and lactatos-pairs), matching the 23 values of `alto_grado_data`

Comment: It worked!! Apparently it was the shape tuple in the input layer. Thanks a lot!